# Unable to send mail - javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send email using apache james with this code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String user = "sumit";  // Newly created user on JAMES
    String password = "sumit"; // user password

    String fromAddress = "sumit@localhost"; // newlycreateduser@localhost
    String toAddress = "sumitjain91@gmail.com";

    // Create a mail session
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.username", user);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    try
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));

        message.setSubject("Email from our JAMES Server");
        message.setText("Luke, I'm your father!!");
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Email sent successfully");
    }
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:784)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:720)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:660)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:640)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:192)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at mail.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Please help

Comment: what happens from `telnet localhost 25`?  How about running James from the console?  `./james console` or `./james help` (at least for James3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some [googling](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1137&bih=592&q=javax.mail.nosuchproviderexception%20smtp&aq=0&aqi=g1g-m1&aql=&oq=javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException%3a%20smtp)...

Your problem sounds like a classpath issue.

Verify that you only have one version of both the mail.jar and activation.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are missing a properties setting which would set the transport protocol to smtp

```
  properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```